# DidfinshLoad for imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:srcAddres]];?

Tags: iphone

```
imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:srcAddres]];
```

Downloading jpeg to my imagedata  will spend some time,for example: 2 second, so I want to show an activity indicator until the downloading finished. How can I know when the downloading has finished??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this version of the method:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)aURL options:(NSUInteger)mask error:(NSError **)errorPtr
```

Make sure you pass in an NSError pointer by declaring one before you make the call:

```
NSError *error
```

...and then passing the error as:

```
&error
```

If error is not nil then you have a problem.  You can then inspect the error to give proper user feedback.  I won't go into the mask here.  [You can read all about this method in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BCIBCEBC).